# Get current Page Path when triggering tags with Link Click on Next.js project

Tags: reactjs, next.js, google-tag-manager, next-router

I have a Next.js project and I need the current page path when I click (triggering) on some links to my GA4 tags. The problem is that the value of the Page Path variable is incorrect, because without completely reloading the application and quickly changing routes, the Page Path returned is the link's destination page, and not the current page. This actually happens due to delay, if I test in slower environments (localhost for example) where loading takes longer, the value returned is the correct one, that is, the Page Path before the route is changed.

I've already tried creating a data layer variable with the page path in the code, but the same thing happens.

```
useEffect(() => {
  //Update GTM data layer pagePath variable
  pushEvent({
    pagePath: asPath
  })
}, [pathname])
```

Does anyone have any idea how to get this value in a generic way? I have several tags and we won't always have a developer available to do this, so this has to be resolved by GTM or in a definitive way in the code.